# Is there mismatch in injures or death numbers for carnivores that hunt during day time and night time?

Tags: evolution, zoology, ethology

Is there significant mismatch in injures or death numbers for hunters (when hunter was killed or injured by its prey), between day time and night time hunts (carnivores that hunt during the day time and night time)?

Comment: Such animals could be:  lions, leopards, hyenas, wild dogs, wolfs. Basically I am looking for such type data (if there is one) that could give me insight into  the night time hunt as a risk factor for hunter.